# Mimic windows wildcard search using PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

got an requirement to find whether document has any ip address in it.
do we have any PowerShell script/command to do it for any file type.
I found few script which works only for .txt files.

Comment: IPv4 or IPv6? Decimal octet notation only? What else does the file contain? How big is it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to search for an IP address in any file type, you need to solve two basic problems.

One, PowerShell needs to perform searches against the contents of any file type.

Two, the search needs to define an IP address.

---

For the first problem, it is possible to search the contents of common file types using Windows Search. However, Windows Search does not have a practical way of searching for an IP address. It is good at searching for human-readable text like "apple pie". It does not have useful [wild card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-sql-fulltextpredicates) or [declarative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-sql-featuresunavailableinspssearch) syntax that would be suitable for IP addresses. You'd be better off searching for "IP address" as far as Windows Search is concerned.

---

For the second problem, there are many strings which could qualify as an IP address:

- 172.16.0.1
- 192.0.2.0/24
- 10.x.x.x
- 2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
- 2001:db8::8a2e:370:7334

Typically, developing a solution would start with defining an appropriate regular expression. You can find some help online. But it would take work to cover everything that qualifies as "any ip address".

- [IP Address Regex - IP Address Regular Expression](https://www.ipregex.com/)

---

The scenario you are describing is commonly known as *eDiscovery*. You might search for a product that will do what you ask.

---

So that others can benefit from my research, here is a working example using Windows Search in PowerShell. Here, I search for `PowerShell` in the `C:/Users/Michael/Stack Overflow` directory. Notice the search term is relatively simple which is a limitation of the full-text search.

Make sure to scroll down and copy the whole script.

```
# Adapted from 
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-sample-wsfromscript
# and 
# https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/WindowsSearch/WSFromScript/QueryEverything.vbs

# See 
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-sql-folderdepth
# for information on searching specific directories. 

# See
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-sql-contains
# for information on searching the body of a document. 

# See 
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/core-bumper
# for potential properties to return. 


# Create the ADO objects. 
$objConnection = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Connection 
$objRecordSet  = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Recordset 

# Windows Search connection string. 
$objConnection.Open("Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows';") 

# SQL SELECT statement specifies what properties to return, you can add more if you want
#     FROM - use SystemIndex for a local query or MACHINENAME.SystemIndex for remote
#     WHERE - specify restrictions including SCOPE and other conditions that must be true

# To add scope restriction append "WHERE SCOPE='file:c:/users'" to the query string.

# SQL Query
$objRecordSet.Open("SELECT System.ItemName, System.ItemTypeText, System.Size, System.ItemPathDisplay FROM SystemIndex WHERE SCOPE='file:C:/Users/Michael/Stack Overflow' AND CONTAINS('PowerShell')", $objConnection) 

try 
{
    $objRecordSet.MoveFirst()
    do {
        # Access the column values that were specified in the SELECT statement here
        Write-Host $objRecordset.Fields.Item("System.ItemName").Value
        Write-Host $objRecordset.Fields.Item("System.ItemTypeText").Value
        Write-Host $objRecordset.Fields.Item("System.Size").Value
        Write-Host $objRecordset.Fields.Item("System.ItemPathDisplay").Value
        Write-Host 
        $objRecordset.MoveNext()
    } until ($objRecordset.EOF) 
}
finally 
{
    $objRecordset.Close()
    Remove-Variable -Name objRecordset
    $objConnection.Close()
    Remove-Variable -Name objConnection 
}
# Script End
```

Sample run.

```
PS > & '.\QueryEverything 03.ps1'

...

Stack Overflow Notes.txt
Text Document
3606
C:\Users\Michael\Stack Overflow\in-powershell-can-you-write-host-the-invocation-and-arguments-for-an-external-co\Stack Overflow Notes.txt

Stack Overflow Answer.txt
Text Document
1720
C:\Users\Michael\Stack Overflow\mimic-windows-wildcard-search-using-powershell-script\Stack Overflow Answer.txt

Stack Overflow Notes.txt
Text Document
23310
C:\Users\Michael\Stack Overflow\mimic-windows-wildcard-search-using-powershell-script\Stack Overflow Notes.txt
```

---

Take care to note that "mimic windows wildcard search" refers to the *file name* in practice. I'm not aware of a way to use wild cards against the body of a document except a trailing asterisk like this:

```
CONTAINS('PowerSh*')
```